# When using DoctrineFixturesBundle, how can I capture the exact SQL that's being executed when they're being loaded?

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, fixtures

When using [DoctrineFixturesBundle](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle), how can I capture the exact SQL that's being executed when they're being loaded? I have fixtures to load in, but I don't have access to that server -- I need to send an SQL file to the administrator.

Comment: You could setup a local mysql server, load the fixtures in it, and then give a dump to your admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue on this bundle:

https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle/issues/60

> I don't think this is possible as doctrine:fixtures:load does not deal with SQL but works at the ORM level.

Answer (score 0):

Can't try it out right now, but what happends when you:

```
var_dump($object->flush());
```

Within the load() method.

Comment: What object are you talking about?

Comment: I was referencing this:
https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures#doctrine-data-fixtures-extension